# MySQL ORDER BY CASE - ER_TABLENAME_NOT_ALLOWED_HERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following part of my query below which I need to change `WHEN 5 THEN 0` to `WHEN 5 THEN wk.week_pk`.

However `wk.week_pk` is not recognised in that part of the query: `ER_TABLENAME_NOT_ALLOWED_HERE: Table 'wk' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list`

Relevant part of the long query is:

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       5 AS seq
FROM week wk 
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lewk.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN week wk ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lewk ON wk.week_pk = lewk.week_fk and lewk.week_fk <> 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lerdb.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lerdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = lerdb.rotation_discipline_block_fk AND lerdb.week_fk = 0

ORDER BY seq, 
    CASE seq
    WHEN 1 THEN 0 
    WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, -2) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 4 THEN 0
    WHEN 5 THEN 0
    WHEN 6 THEN 0
    END,
    name  ASC
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u7wqE9GpHiv3y6NpvVn2bn/0)

Comment: You can order only those columns which are on the select list. There is no such column as week_pk on the select list hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, so how should I change the query to be able to order case 5 on wk.week_pk?

Comment: See the below answer.

Comment: Important to note that "You can order only those columns which are on the select list" it is correct only when selecting from virtual table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dummy column for your `week_pk`. So you can include it on your `order by`

```
select t1.global_id, t1.name, t1.parent_global_id, t1.seq from (SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id,
       1 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       2 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk        
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
       3 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id,
       4 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS global_id,
       week_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       5 AS seq
       ,wk.week_pk
FROM week wk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lewk.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',week:', week_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN week wk ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = wk.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lewk ON wk.week_pk = lewk.week_fk and lewk.week_fk <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
      lerdb.learning_event_name AS name,
CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id,
       6 AS seq
       ,0 as weekpk
FROM year y
INNER JOIN unit u ON y.year_pk = u.year_fk
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN learning_event lerdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = lerdb.rotation_discipline_block_fk AND lerdb.week_fk = 0) t1
ORDER BY seq ASC, 
    CASE seq
    WHEN 1 THEN 0 
    WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, 6) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 3 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(name, -2) AS SIGNED)
    WHEN 4 THEN 0
    WHEN 5 THEN t1.weekpk
    WHEN 6 THEN 0
    END ASC,
    name  ASC
```